# android (flutter) - App downloaded from Google Play Store crashing after Splash screen in Android 12, but working fine locally even in release build

Tags: android, flutter, apk, google-play-console, android-12

We have had our app published to Play Store for a very long time. but recently we got this issue in Android 12.

[Image showing Google Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6QAD.png)

There are two types of APK in Play Console

1. Original File
2. Distribution APK

this problem is happening in the distribution app

I checked the logcat with adb but it's only showing WINDEATH and there is no other crash

I have checked all over Google and StackOverflow but there is no such question asked that I came across

After opening the app it's showing it like this
[App Crash Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDV8H.jpg)

Also, we are using Firebase but there is nothing captured related to this

Comment: There are many crash report tools that you can use. Like firebase crashlytics(https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics), implement one of them and maybe you will get lucky :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a crash reporting service such as Firebase
or Sentry.io.

These will help you log the crash, get some data about when it happened, why it happened etc. Flutter apps are not meant to crash, so check out your interactions with 3rd party plugins that are initiated on app start. Also, check your signing keys, maybe there is a mismatch between the debug ones and the production ones.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are using Firebase but there is nothing captured in Firebase. and the APKs in Google Play Console are signed with the same key and they are working in other devices even android 12 but in a few, they are failing.

I have added crash image to the question